# How to traverse/iterate JsonNode to find parents of particular node

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, rest-assured

I am trying to create custom deserializator of some REST response. This is example of returned object:

```
"someField": [
        {
            "key": "foo",
            "value": {
                "left": "bar_left",
                "right": "bar_right"
            }
        },

        {
            "key": "foo2",
            "value": {
                "left": "bar_left2",
                "right": "bar_right2"
            }
        }
    ],
"anotherField: [
        {
            "key": "foo3",
            "value": {
                "left": "bar_left",
                "right": "bar_right"
            }
        },

        {
            "key": "foo4",
            "value": {
                "left": "bar_left2",
                "right": "bar_right2"
            }
        }
    ],
"someMoreField": {}
```

What I am trying to achieve is retrieval of `left` and `right` value based on given `key` (which is unique).

So far I got something like that:

```
List<JsonNode> keys = rootNode.findValues("key");

for (JsonNode keyNode: keys ) {
    if (keyNode.asText().equals("foo")) {
        System.out.println("NODE FOUND!");
        //and here I would like to go one node up:
        JsonNode parent = keyNode.getParent(); //such method doesn't exist
        System.out.println(parent.get("left"));
    }
}
```

Because JsonNode is one-way linked there is no possibility to access parent node.

Does someone of you know how could I efficiently iterate/parse JsonNode throw **all levels** so I could compare `key` value while keeping reference to the parent?

I have something like that on my mind:

```
JsonNode rootNode = //some retrieval blablalbal
JsonNode parent = rootNode;
Iterator<JsonNode> it = rootNode.iterateAllLevels()
while (it.hasNext()) {
    JsonNode current = it.next();
    if(current.asText().equals("searched key")) {
         parent.get("value");
    }
    parent = current;
}
```

Maybe there is some other way to achieve that?

Comment: how about writing classes that represents the structure and use Jackson to create object out of the json response...

Comment: That's not the point here. I need to extract few values from a really complex object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to *extract few values from a really complex object*, you need to use *JSON Path*. I don't know if you use it in your project, but this is definitely the right tool for your problem. It simply helps you *locate* your elements  based on your criteria. You write down your query and it finds your elements

Information about the lib (installation, set up)  is found [here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). It is very simple to use.

Based on your JSON structure, to find your `left` and `right`, you can use the following path

- left : `$..[?(@.key=='myFooValue')].value.left`
- right: `$..[?(@.key=='myFooValue')].value.rigth`

with `myFooValue` being the value of your input `key`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @MaciejTreder happy It could help you !!